# How to use Reduce on Scala

Tags: scala

I am using scala to implement an algorithm. I have a case where I need to implement such scenario:

```
test = Map(t -> List((t,2)), B -> List((B,3), (B,1)), D -> List((D,1)))
```

I need to some the second member of every common tuples.

The desired result :

```
Map((t,2),(B,4),(D,1))

val resReduce = test.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, List[Map.empty[String, Int]]){(count, tup) => count + (tup -> (count.getOrElse(tup, 0) + 1))
```

I am trying to use "Reduce", I have to go through every group I did and sum their second member. Any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that all lists are nonempty and start with the same key (e.g. they were produced by `groupBy`), then you can just

```
test.mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum).toMap
```

Alternatively, you might want an intermediate step that allows you to perform error-checking:

```
test.map{ case(k,xs) =>
  val v = {
    if (xs.exists(_._1 != k)) ???   // Handle key-mismatch case
    else xs.reduceOption((l,r) => l.copy(_2 = l._2 + r._2))
  }
  v.getOrElse(??? /* Handle empty-list case */)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
 test collect{
   case (key, many) => (key, many.map(_._2).sum)
 }
```

wherein you do not have to assume that the list has any members. However, if you want to exclude empty lists, add a guard

```
   case (key, many) if many.nonEmpty =>
```

like that.

Comment: There is a small error here:  "value map is not a member of Any"at many.map(_._2)

Comment: You can't possibly mean `reduce`; the type signature is all wrong.  Maybe you were thinking of `collect` (and would use the guard to discard empty lists)?

Comment: @RexKerr Yes, `collect` was what I was thinking of. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val test = Map("t" -> List(("t",2)), "B" -> List(("B",3), ("B",1)), "D" -> List(("D",1)))
test: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[(String, Int)]] = Map(t -> List((t,2)), B -> List((B,3), (B,1)), D -> List((D,1)))


scala> test.map{case (k,v) => (k, v.map(t => t._2).sum)}
res32: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(t -> 2, B -> 4, D -> 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach, in essence quite similar to what has already been suggested,

```
implicit class mapAcc(val m: Map[String,List[(String,Int)]]) extends AnyVal {
  def mapCount() = for ( (k,v) <- m ) yield { (k,v.map {_._2}.sum) }
}
```

Then for a given

```
val test = Map("t" -> List(("t",2)), "B" -> List(("B",3), ("B",1)), "D" -> List(("D",1)))
```

a call

```
test.mapCount()
```

delivers

```
Map(t -> 2, B -> 4, D -> 1)
```